# Facebook API: Send friends request graph api 2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Between users.

What is the best way to do this in graph API 2.0, the old method seems to have been removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send friend requests using the Graph API. The only way to send friend requests is to use the official Facebook clients or facebook.com. You can´t automate this in any (legal) way. But i would not know any serious situation where you would need to automate sending friend requests anyway, to be honest.